# Problem when selected custom tabbar item (cbflashytabbarcontroller)

Tags: ios, swift

I use cbflashytabbarcontroller "[from](https://github.com/Cuberto/flashy-tabbar/tree/master/CBFlashyTabBarController)". When I selected tabBar item programmatically, the item is selected but the image is hidden and the title also, both in the first item and in the second item.
[Before select tab bar item = 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7ZgZ.jpg)

[After select tab bar item = 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8yUE.jpg)

In the tabBar Controller

```
self.selectedIndex = 1
```

Comment: Hi Hanen, how are you selecting the tabBar item programmatically? Can you please update your post with code snipet.

Answer (score 0):

Probably that icon for selected state is same color as tab bar or is nil.

Comment: when i selected it manually it works, but when I selected it programmatically the problem appear